# Is it haram to buy from fast fashion & if u did then what can u do

Tags: halal-haram, hadith, fiqh, sharia, clothing

‏السلام عليكم so my question is I heard that fast fashion is haram so is it? & what if u we’re to buy clothes from one of these shops like shien & is shein fast fashion or haram to buy from? & if it is, & u bought clothes from these types of stores while not knowing it’s fast fashion, but later realized, so then is it permissible for me to wear the clothes that I bought from the store if it’s not returnable or will it be me haram to wear the clothes & for context I bought these clothes long ago